# Use NCEP/NOAA .bin file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read .bin files from NOAA (ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd53rl/cfsr/) using R version 2.14.0 on a PC. 
When I read the files using the function readBin, the values are very high (from 1e16 to 9e16) while they should not be higher than 330.

I wrote the code below to download the .zip file containing the information (Note: the number 20130422 is related 
to the date, thus another date may be available).

```
    file.name <- 'Data.zip' 
    file.URL <- 'ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd53rl/cfsr/cargill.20130422.zip' 
    download.file(file.URL,file.name)
```

I unzipped the files manually and used the one with max temperature data (tmax.20130422.daily.latlon.bin)

Then, I wrote a code to read the max temperature file (720*720 is the number of rows and columns I want to read):

```
    to.read <- 'tmax.20130422.daily.latlon.bin' 
    bin <- readBin(to.read, what = 'numeric',n = 720*720,endian='little')
```

I have tried to use different "endian" or "what", but nothing worked for me. How can I extract the right values from the bin file?

Thanks, 
Eduardo

Comment: I would hunt down the data provider and find out the structure of the file so you can specify this properly. How do you know that it is 720x720 for example?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you managed to solve this but I had a similar issue with NOAA data. My data was from lat -40 to 40 and lon -20 to 55, with a 0.1 degree spacing. Therefore it had 751 columns and 801 rows. Even though NOAA said it was 'little' endian, I found 'big' endian worked for my machine. Also, I had to flip my data so the matrix matched the way R read it in and plotted it. Finally I overlaid a map of Africa, as my data was for rainfall data over Africa. I also installed 'raster', 'maps' and 'mapdata' packages.

Below is my solution:

```
infile <- file("clim.bin.0101", "rb")
outfile <- matrix(readBin(infile, "numeric", 
                      n = 751 * 801, size = 4, 
                      endian = "big"), ncol= 751, 
              nrow = 801, byrow = TRUE);    
close(infile)
tran_outfile <- apply(outfile,2,rev) #flips the matirx so data is in correct order 
r = raster(tran_outfile)
extent(r) = extent(c(xmn=-20,xmx=55,ymn=-40,ymx=40))
plot(r)
plot(wrld_simpl, add=T)
```

Hope that helps